# unable to maintain the same order of the row when writing to a csv file in python

Tags: python

I have written a python code which will read a json file and extract all the keys and check if these keys are present in a txt file and if the key is present then it will take the values from the json file for the respective key and then it will be written to a CSV file. I am able to get the expected result but in the csv file the order of keys in the first column is different than the txt file.

Following is my python code

```
import json
import csv
def read_json_file(file1):
        with open(file1, 'r') as fh:
           data = json.load(fh)
           for i,j in data.items():
               with open("test.txt", 'r') as ft:
                   for line in ft:
                       if i in line:
                            yield i, j["a"], j["b"], j["c"], j["d"]


a=list(read_json_file("/home/user/Downloads/data.json"))
print(a)   

with open('data.csv','w') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow(['name','a','b','c','d']
    for row in a:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

IF following is the content of my test.txt

apple
goa
tea
orange
bux

When output is written to the csv file the same above order should be followed in the first column followed by the respective values in other columns. Instead the csv file has a different order

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

> take the values from the json file for the respective key and then it
> will be written to a CSV file. I am able to get the expected result
> but in the csv file the order of keys in the first column is different
> than the txt file.

[`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) (part of python standard library) does implement [RFC 7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159.html) which enforce that

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs,
> where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean,
> null, object, or array.

Therefore you must not assume that there is any particular order when you load JSON holding object which is then turned into `python`'s `dict`.